# Python 3.5 ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_cv2)

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, ubuntu

This is what I'm getting when i try to import cv2 into python3.5 IDLE. 
I'm using OpenCV 3.1.0 Python3.5.2 Ubuntu 16.04

I tried lots of installing methods but no one solved my problem, i had the import working on terminal but it just stopped as well.
Anyone might have a solution?

```
import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2
ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_cv2)
```

Edit: I followed the tutorials on this links:

http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-last-rst/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html

http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/07/20/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-3-4-on-ubuntu/

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem after I installed other versions of OpenCV (for various reasons, one of them installing ROS, which has its own OpenCV version).  It seems this caused a conflict.  To make sure that PyOpenCV gets loaded correctly enter an interactive session and check:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

You can try that inside IDLE as well.

The path to cv2.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so should appear there.  If it doesn't, insert it to path:

```
sys.path.insert(1, '<path to .../dist-packages with cpython so>')
```

Make sure it goes before any other option which may be causing conflict.  Then try again:

```
import cv2
```

It should work now and that would mean the problem was the python path.  It may also help to figure out what is causing conflict in your case and how is best to solve it for you.

Answer (score 0):

For python3, you need to provide python a `init` method as entrance,

which is in `cv.py` I guess. But in my case,

this file did not exist. I copied own from [google code](https://code.google.com/p/ctypes-opencv/source/browse/trunk/src/ctypes_opencv/cv.py?r=236).

If the `cv.py` is not provided,

you may get error `ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (PyInit_cv2)` when `import cv2` in python3 (no such problem in python2).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it solved the problem in the terminal, but i still have it in the IDLE

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem when I was working on a computer with a ROS environment. The simplest solution for me was to not source the ROS environment in .bashrc by commenting out the line and restarting the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, which was caused by the `cv2.so` file in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so`. After I deleted the file and use command `sudo pip3 install opencv-python`, it worked for python3. Hope that will help.

Answer (score -3):

First you need get-pip.py, it's a great tool to install pip, never had any problem :

> wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py

Then you need to install pip for python3, I have python3.5 but this would work for any version I believe :

> python3.5 get-pip.py

Now pip is installed for python3.5 and in order to use it with python3.4 you need to call it within python3.5 like this :

> python3.5 -m pip

So if you want to install numpy you would use :

> python3.5 -m pip install numpy