# ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_cv2) - Linux 16.10 and Python 3.5.2+

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, cmake, opencv3.0

First of all, sorry for my english. It's not my native language.

Second, i already saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36070215/importerror-dynamic-module-does-not-define-module-export-function-pyinit-cv2) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39112321/python-3-5-importerror-dynamic-module-does-not-define-module-export-function-p), and got no help at all.

Well, i'm searching for a solution for 2 days and i got no clue, so i'll try you folks.

I was install OpenCV 3.0.1 with Python 3.5.2+ on my Ubuntu 16.10 OS (with virtualenvwrapper), and everything was fine, except for my cmake build. It get python 3 interpretor, but don't get the Library. I "make install" it anyway. cmake print below:

> --   GUI: 
>   --     QT:                          NO
>   --     GTK+ 3.x:                    YES (ver 3.20.9)
>   --     GThread :                    YES (ver 2.50.2)
>   --     GtkGlExt:                    NO
>   --     OpenGL support:              NO
>
> ### --     VTK support:                 NO
>
> --   Media I/O: 
>   --     ZLib:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (ver 1.2.8)
>   --     JPEG:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so (ver )
>   --     WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020e)
>   --     PNG:                         /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng.so (ver 1.6.25)
>   --     TIFF:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so (ver 42 - 4.0.6)
>   --     JPEG 2000:                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjasper.so (ver 1.900.1)
>   --     OpenEXR:                     build (ver 1.7.1)
>   --     GDAL:                        NO
>
> ### --     GDCM:                        NO
>
> --   Video I/O:
>   --     DC1394 1.x:                  NO
>   --     DC1394 2.x:                  NO
>   --     FFMPEG:                      YES
>   --       avcodec:                   YES (ver 57.24.102)
>   --       avformat:                  YES (ver 57.25.100)
>   --       avutil:                    YES (ver 55.17.103)
>   --       swscale:                   YES (ver 4.0.100)
>   --       avresample:                NO
>   --     GStreamer:                   NO
>   --     OpenNI:                      NO
>   --     OpenNI PrimeSensor Modules:  NO
>   --     OpenNI2:                     NO
>   --     PvAPI:                       NO
>   --     GigEVisionSDK:               NO
>   --     Aravis SDK:                  NO
>   --     UniCap:                      NO
>   --     UniCap ucil:                 NO
>   --     V4L/V4L2:                    NO/YES
>   --     XIMEA:                       NO
>   --     Xine:                        NO
>
> ### --     gPhoto2:                     NO
>
> ### --   Parallel framework:            pthreads
>
> --   Other third-party libraries:
>   --     Use IPP:                     9.0.1 [9.0.1]
>   --          at:                     /home/biometriafacial/opencv/source2/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx
>   --     Use IPP Async:               NO
>   --     Use VA:                      NO
>   --     Use Intel VA-API/OpenCL:     NO
>   --     Use Lapack:                  NO
>   --     Use Eigen:                   NO
>   --     Use Cuda:                    NO
>   --     Use OpenCL:                  YES
>   --     Use OpenVX:                  NO
>
> ### --     Use custom HAL:              NO
>
> --   OpenCL:                        
>   --     Include path:                /home/biometriafacial/opencv/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
>   --     Use AMDFFT:                  NO
>
> ### --     Use AMDBLAS:                 NO
>
> --   Python 2:
>   --     Interpreter:                 /home/biometriafacial/.virtualenvs/cv/bin/python (ver 2.7.12)
>   --     Libraries:                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so (ver 2.7.12+)
>   --     numpy:                       /home/biometriafacial/.virtualenvs/cv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include
>   (ver 1.12.1)
>
> ### --     packages path:               lib/python2.7/site-packages
>
> --   Python 3:
>
> ### --     Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python3 (ver 3.5.2)
>
> ### --   Python (for build):            /home/biometriafacial/.virtualenvs/cv/bin/python
>
> --   Java:
>   --     ant:                         NO
>   --     JNI:                         NO
>   --     Java wrappers:               NO
>
> ### --     Java tests:                  NO
>
> ### --   Matlab:                        Matlab not found or implicitly disabled
>
> --   Documentation:
>
> ### --     Doxygen:                     NO
>
> --   Tests and samples:
>   --     Tests:                       YES
>   --     Performance tests:           YES
>
> ### --     C/C++ Examples:              YES
>
> ### --   Install path:                  /usr/local
>
> --   cvconfig.h is in:              /home/biometriafacial/opencv/source2
>
> ### -- -----------------------------------------------------------------
>
> -- Configuring done
>   -- Generating done
>   -- Build files have been written to: /home/biometriafacial/opencv/source2

Look at **Python 3 Interpreter**, there is no Library found. Well, i make install anyway, and when i try to import cv2, the exception below appears.

> Python 3.5.2+ (default, Sep 22 2016, 12:18:14)  [GCC 6.2.0 20160927]
>   on linux Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more
>   information.
>
> > > > import cv2 Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in  ImportError: dynamic module does not define module
> > > >         export function (PyInit_cv2)

If you've read up to this point, i appreciate it. I'll await your reply.

Comment: hey any luck, even i got stuck at the same point

Comment: Not yet. I keep trying, but i'm still stuck on the same problem.

Comment: @lakshaman buddy, i give up. I'm making the installation in python 2.7 to use OpenCV + OpenFace (this is my objective at the start), and it's going ok. If someone helps below, that's ok, but i don't think i'll be able to test. You can get this post to you for test, if you want.

Comment: hi, i tried my best to get the things work from my side. i am end up repeating the procedure and getting the same results. So Even i also started looking into Python2.7 rather than try to waste the time in installing OpenCV 3.0 in Python3.0

Comment: Now i am trying to install the OpenCV + Python 2.7 in Raspberry pi.

Comment: At Ubuntu 16.10 it's working (Python 2.7 + OpenCV + OpenFace). I'm using since the past week. I have some ideas to make my project works in a Raspberry sometime, but it's not priority now.

Good luck on your try :)