# Cython : importing a .pyd file returns an error (lack of an init function ?)

Tags: python, cython, cythonize

I am learning how to use Cython to compile efficiently a Python code and make it quicker.

Here is what I've done so far:

1. I created a Python file called `math_code_python.py` and put 4 simple functions in it.
2. I saved that file as `math_code_cython.pyx`.
3. I created a setup file called `setup.py`.
4. I typed `python C:\Users\loic\Documents\math_code\setup.py build_ext --inplace` in my `Command Prompt`.
5. I got a compiled file called `math_code_cython.cp36-win_amd64.pyd` that I renamed `math_code_pyd.pyd`.
6. Finally, I created a Python file called `test_math_code.pyd` with only `import math_code_pyd` in it. When I executed this file I got that message:

   ```
   ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function
   ```

I did some research and thanks to those posts I understood that I had to provide an `init function`:

- https://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/694888-constructor-initialization-function-module
- [Python 3.5 ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_cv2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39112321/python-3-5-importerror-dynamic-module-does-not-define-module-export-function-p)

My question is : how do I do that ? Do I have to put a function at the end of `math_code_python.py` like what follows ?

```
def __init__(self):
    # something ?
```

---

My version of Python:

```
Python 3.6.1 |Anaconda 4.4.0 (64-bit)| (default, May 11 2017, 13:25:24) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

## math_code_python.py

```
def fact(n):
    if n==0 or n==1:
        return 1
    else:
        return n*fact(n-1)

def fibo(n):
    if n==0 or n==1:
        return 1
    else:
        return fibo(n-1)+fibo(n-2)

def dicho(f, a, b, eps):
    assert f(a)*f(b) < 0
    while b-a > eps:
        M = (a+b)/2.
        if f(a) * f(M) > 0:
            a = M
        else:
            b = M
    return M

def newton(f, fp, x0, eps):
    u = x0
    v = u - f(u)/fp(u)
    while abs(v-u) > eps:
        u = v
        v = u - f(u)/fp(u)
    return v
```

## setup.py

```
try:
    from setuptools import setup
except ImportError:
    from distutils.core import setup

from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
from Cython.Build import cythonize

import numpy as np

setup(name = "maido",
      include_dirs = [np.get_include()],
      cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
      ext_modules = cythonize(r"C:\Users\loic\Documents\math_code\math_code_cython.pyx"),
      )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is renaming the pyd file. When you call `import math_code_pyd` it specifically looks for `initmath_code_pyd` (Python2) or `PyInit_math_code_pyd` (Python3).

When you compile it with Cython it generates a function matched to the .pyx filename (i.e. `initmath_code_cython` or `PyInit_math_code_cython`). Hence it doesn't find the function it expects to. *You don't have to provide this function yourself - Cython generates it.*

Simply name your .pyx file what you want your module to be called and don't rename the .pyd file. (In principle you could remove the `.cp36-win_amd64` but it is useful and there for a reason).